# Not able to deserialize json data into structs

Tags: json, struct, go, deserialization

I'm a newbie to go and trying to write a simple app to pull some school data from greatschools.org. The json data looks like this:

```
{
    "schools": {
        "school": [
            {
                "gsId": 1,
                "name": "Catholic School",
                "type": "private",
                "gradeRange": "PK-9",
                "enrollment": 39,
                "parentRating": 4,
                "city": "Denver",
                "state": "CO",
                "address": "111 Main St., \nDenver, CO  80100",
                "phone": "(720) 555-1212",
                "fax": "(720) 555-1212",
                "website": "http://www.myschool.org",
                "ncesId": "1234567",
                "lat": 30.519446,
                "lon": -105.71314,
                "overviewLink": "http://www.greatschools.org/colorado/Denver/1-Catholic-School/?s_cid=gsapi",
                "ratingsLink": "http://www.greatschools.org/school/rating.page?state=CO&id=1&s_cid=gsapi",
                "reviewsLink": "http://www.greatschools.org/school/parentReviews.page?state=CO&id=1&s_cid=gsapi",
                "schoolStatsLink": "http://www.greatschools.org/cgi-bin/CO/otherprivate/1"
            }...
```

My structs look like this:

```
type SchoolStruct struct {
    GsId            int
    Name            string
    SchoolType      string
    GradeRange      string
    Enrollment      int
    ParentRating    int
    City            string
    State           string
    Address         string
    Phone           string
    Fax             string
    Website         string
    NcesId          string
    Lat             float64
    Lon             float64
    OverviewLink    string
    RatingsLink     string
    ReviewsLink     string
    SchoolStatsLink string
}

type SchoolsStruct struct {
    Schools []SchoolStruct
}
```

When I run my code I get "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.SchoolStruct"

I'm using the [gopencils](https://github.com/bndr/gopencils) library to make my requests and have used it successfully with very simple requests. Do you see what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems.  For starters you are trying to decode a school, but the data is schools, which has a member (an array) of school.

Another issue is you have mismatched names.  `GsId` != `gsid` unless you tell Go about it by using struct tags.

Try decoding to a SchoolResponseData instead:

```
type SchoolResponseData struct {
    Schools struct {
        School []struct {
            Address         string  `json:"address"`
            City            string  `json:"city"`
            Enrollment      float64 `json:"enrollment"`
            Fax             string  `json:"fax"`
            GradeRange      string  `json:"gradeRange"`
            GsId            float64 `json:"gsId"`
            Lat             float64 `json:"lat"`
            Lon             float64 `json:"lon"`
            Name            string  `json:"name"`
            NcesId          string  `json:"ncesId"`
            OverviewLink    string  `json:"overviewLink"`
            ParentRating    float64 `json:"parentRating"`
            Phone           string  `json:"phone"`
            RatingsLink     string  `json:"ratingsLink"`
            ReviewsLink     string  `json:"reviewsLink"`
            SchoolStatsLink string  `json:"schoolStatsLink"`
            State           string  `json:"state"`
            Type            string  `json:"type"`
            Website         string  `json:"website"`
        } `json:"school"`
    } `json:"schools"`
}
```

Comment: The encoding/json package will unmarshal `lowercase` fields into `Uppercase` for you if there's no ambiguity, but it is better to not rely on that behavior.

Comment: Fantastic! Makes perfect sense now. Thank you!